# Multiple packages in catkin workspace?

Tags: ros, catkin.workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I'm just starting out with ROS. I'm trying to create multiple packages in the same workspace, but tab complete fails for some inexplicable (to me) reason. I've outlined the steps below. Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening?

```
mkdir catkin_ws/src
cd catkin_ws/src/
catkin_init_workspace
```

In catkin_ws/src:

```
catkin_create_pkg pkg1
```

Then in catkin_ws

```
catkin_make
source devel/setup.bash
```

This allows me to tab complete rosrun pkg1 ...

However, when I create a second package in catkin_ws/src named 'pkg2' following the same steps, run catkin_make again and try to tab complete 'rosrun pk', I'm only shown 'pkg1'. Shouldn't ROS allow me to create multiple packages in the same folder?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264971/multiple-packages-in-catkin-workspace?/) by [space](https://answers.ros.org/users/30939/space/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-06-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-28**:\

> [..] following the same steps [..]

Which steps are you repeating, specifically?

**Comment by [space](https://answers.ros.org/users/30939/space/) on 2017-06-28**:
In catkin_ws/src:

```
catkin_create_pkg pkg2
```

Then in catkin_ws

```
catkin_make
source devel/setup.bash
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sometimes the rospkg cache isn't updated fast enough when you do these things.

Try -- after you've `source`d `devel/setup.bash` -- to run `rospack profile` and see if that helps.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [space](https://answers.ros.org/users/30939/space/) on 2017-06-28**:
I just tried again without changing anything and it works. Looks like you're right.
rospack profile list the directory structure up to the src folder containing the packages, but not the packages themselves. Is there something else I can do to see if the cache has been updated?
Thanks!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-28**:
I wouldn't bother with the output of `rospack profile` for now, it's not really relevant for your purpose.

**Comment by [space](https://answers.ros.org/users/30939/space/) on 2017-06-28**:
Found the bit detailing what rospack profile does here: http://wiki.ros.org/rospack/Troubleshooting.
Issue resolved. Thanks!